# Replace value in nested documents with matching documents from other collection with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections like this:

```
// collection Shops
[
  {
    "name": "Shop A",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Germany",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "Berlin",
            "districts": [
              {
                "name": "First District",
                "distributor_uid": 123
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

//  Collection Distributors
[
  {
    "uid": 123,
    "name": "Peter",
    "fruits": ["Banana", "Apple"]
  }
]
```

In an aggregation, want to replace all occurence of distributor_uid with matching documents from the Distributors collection and get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Shop A",
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Germany",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "Berlin",
            "districts": [
              {
                "name": "First District",
                "distributor": {
                  "uid": 123,
                  "name": "Peter",
                  "fruits": ["Banana", "Apple"]
                },
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried the following $lookup:

```
db.shops.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: "distributors",
      localField: "countries.cities.districts.distributor_uid",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "countries.cities.districts.distributor"
    }
  }
])
```

Unfortunately, this just puts all matching distributor documents in a single array to "countries.cities.districts.distributor" and does not add the field distributor individually.

How can I achieve the desired output with the replacement of the field distributor_uid in collection Shops with the respective document from the collection Distributors?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for optimized solution then please take a look at this 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/H4QnAnzkjCT

Comment: Sure, I appreciate any optimized solution :) Unfortunately, the solution you propose does not replace the distributor_uid wit the respective doc from the distributor collection, but it adds the same array of docs of distributors replacing every distributor_uid. A shorter solution that works is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$lookup` stage results in creating/overriding the field with an array value. It will not *merge* the data to the current field.

You need a `$set` stage to manually combine the nested element with the matched element by `uid`.

```
db.shops.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "distributors",
      localField: "countries.cities.districts.distributor_uid",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "distributors"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      countries: {
        $map: {
          input: "$countries",
          as: "country",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$country",
              {
                cities: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$country.cities",
                    as: "city",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$city",
                        {
                          districts: {
                            $map: {
                              input: "$$city.districts",
                              as: "district",
                              in: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                  "$$district",
                                  {
                                    distributor: {
                                      $first: {
                                        $filter: {
                                          input: "$distributors",
                                          cond: {
                                            $eq: [
                                              "$$this.uid",
                                              "$$district.distributor_uid"
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "countries.cities.districts.distributor_uid",
      "countries.cities.districts.distributor._id"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QXnkIQeeBIZ)